# RingGeometry rotate in three.js

Tags: three.js

I followed a example to create a planet ring with the following code.

```
    createRing(){
        const TEXTURE_PATH = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123879/';

        let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        loader.setCrossOrigin( 'https://s.codepen.io' );
        var ringTexture = loader.load( TEXTURE_PATH + 'saturnrings.png' );
        let saturnRadius = 0.98;
        var ringGeometry = new THREE.RingGeometry(1.4 * saturnRadius, 2.5 * saturnRadius, 2 * 32, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        var ringMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: ringTexture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            transparent: true,
            opacity: 0.7,
        });
        
        var ring = new THREE.Mesh( ringGeometry, ringMaterial );  
        scene.add(ring);
   }
```

the code works to show a planet and planet ring as shown in the image below.

[image]

then I tried to rotate the ring with the code,

```
ring.rotation.set(new THREE.Vector3(  Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 ));
```

however the ring just disappear with only the planet left.

what goes wrong with it

Comment: What is `XRingGeometry`? Where are you getting that class from? Three.js only has [`RingGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/RingGeometry), without the `X`

Comment: Try `ring.rotation.set( Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 );`